# Are 'addition' and 'bitwise or' the same in this case?

Tags: c++, c, math, bitwise-operators, addition

Say I have four 32-bit numbers, defined so that their bits don't overlap, i.e.

```
unsigned long int num0 = 0xFF000000;
unsigned long int num1 = 0x00FF0000;
unsigned long int num2 = 0x0000FF00;
unsigned long int num3 = 0x000000FF;
```

Where in each number one could have anything in the place of the `FF`s.

Am I right in saying that *addition* and *bitwise or* would always produce the same output for such sort of numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: As a third alternative, you could also use exclusive-or, that is, the `^` operator.

Comment: But note that if you want to combine such numbers into one it is good style to use `|`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

as long as for two numbers num1 and num2 applies `num1 & num2 == 0`, then follows:

`num1 + num2 == num1 | num2`

the reason for this is, that addition is basically a bitwise XOR, *plus* carry bit. But as long as there are no carry bits (`num1 & num2 == 0`) then addition boils down to bitwise XOR, which is (again because of `num1 & num2 == 0`) in this case logically equivalent to a bitwise OR

Comment: wouldn't it be more accurate to say that addition is a bitwise `XOR` plus a carry?

Comment: Is one faster than the other?

Comment: @KyleDelaney the answer to that question does not fit into a comment box :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as (seen bitwise) `0+1` is the same as `0|1`. The only difference is `1|1 (=1)` vs. `1+1(=0b10)`, i.e. create a 0 and having overflow, affecting the bits to the left).

So in your case both are equivalent. But you should go to the safe side and choose the less error-prone one.

Answer (score 6):

No:

```
num3 + num3 => 0x000001FE

num3 | num3 => 0x000000FF
```

Of course, as long as you ensure that you only add things together where you know that they don't have the same bits set, you should be safe.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to implicitly exclude this case.

Comment: And because you will forget it again next time (everyone does) always use `|` for logical expressions. - In contrast to when you are really calculating, i.e. in cases where, say, the decimal representation also makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're not doing something like `num3 + num3`, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the bitwise addition adds more than one 1 (either because the sources have them, or the carry from another place is 1 too), then a carry is produced and one place affects the other. As long as in an addition there is at most one 1 added, things are the same as bitwise or.

This can also be seen when we look at the adder circuits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29), where when no carry is produced, all elements taking part in the circuit are the "or" elements.

Answer (score 0):

Addition and bit-wise or would be the same as bit-wise or would include any bits in either, and normal addition would do exactly the same given the mutually exclusive nature of your bits.