# what is the difference between logical OR operation and binary addition?

Tags: xor

I'm trying to understand how a binary addition and logical OR table differs.
does both carry forward 1 or if not which one does carry forward operation and which does not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are 'addition' and 'bitwise or' the same in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334832/are-addition-and-bitwise-or-the-same-in-this-case)

Answer (score 4):

The exclusive-or (XOR) operation is like binary addition, except that 
there is no carry from one bit position to the next. Thus, each bit 
position can be evaluated independently of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to clarify a few points with a few illustrations.

First, addition. Basically like adding numbers in grade school. But if you have a 1-bit aligned with a 1-bit, you get a `0` with a `1` carry (i.e. `10`, essentially analogous to `5` plus `5` in base-10). Otherwise, add them like 'regular' (base-10) numbers. For instance:

```
  ₁₁₁   
  1001
+ 1111
______
 11000
```

Note that in the left-most column two `1`'s are added to give `10`, which with another `1` gives `11` (similar to `5 + 5 + 5`).

Now, assuming by "logical OR" you mean something along the lines of bitwise OR (an operation which basically performs the logical OR (*inclusive*) operation on each pair of corresponding bits), then you have this:

```
  1001
| 1111
______
  1111
```

Only case here you should have a `0` bit is if both bits are `0`.

Finally, since you tagged this question `xor`, which I assume is bitwise as well.

```
  1001
^ 1111
______
  0110 = 110₂
```

In this case, two `1`-bits give a `0`, and of course two `0`-bits give `0`.

Answer (score 0):

With a logical OR you get a logical result (Boolean). IOW true OR true is true (anything other than false OR false is true). In some languages (like C) any numeric value other than 0 means true. And some languages use an explicit datatype for true, false (bool, Boolean). 
In case of binary OR, you are ORing the bits of two binary values. ie: 1 (which is binary 1) bitwise OR 2 (which is binary 10) is binary 11:

01

### 10

11

which is 3. Thus binary OR is also an addition when the values do not have shared bits (like flag values).